# CakePhp - how does it combine files for result

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller

I've seen the diagrams, but I want a description of how it all works -- for example -- cakephp uses the controller file and the view file. What happens?  Is there anything out there?  It would make using cakephp's mvc easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most simple request would look something like the following:

when you request a url, the router figures out what is needed and then uses the Dispatcher to open up the controller and run the corresponding method.

As the controller is fired up it includes and builds up the model that corresponds to that controller.

your method will then run and do what ever it needs to do.

When the controller is done calling all the code you have included the view class is executed which starts the rendering. It will include and render the corresponding view file and then the layout that has been set in the code.

all along the way there are a number of callbacks that are triggered in the various parts of the code, like controller::beforeFilter model::afterFind etc. Best to have a look a the api and book for more detailed information or ask a more specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're at all familiar with Object Oriented code and php functions, you can start to read the CakePHP core methods. They will fill in a lot of blanks in terms of understanding the internal mechanics and relationships of Models Controllers and Views.